# Postponed Prime Sieve in Swift

Tags: primes, swift, iterator, swift3

Motivated by [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/136019/unbounded-sieve-of-eratosthenes-in-swift), I looked out for other "infinite prime generators", i.e. functions which produce the list of prime numbers in increasing order and do not have an a-priori upper limit (such as the standard implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes). Repeated calling should produce "all" prime numbers (restricted only by time, available memory, and the limited range of the integer data type).

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10733621) 
(which was [re-written for Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19391111/1187415) later) to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211990/how-to-implement-an-efficient-infinite-generator-of-prime-numbers-in-python) and have implemented that "postponed sieve" algorithm in Swift (Swift 3, Xcode 8 beta 3 required):

```
public final class PostponedPrimeIterator: IteratorProtocol {

    private var basePrimes: PostponedPrimeIterator!
    private var basePrime = 0
    private var basePrimeSquared = 0

    private var sieve: [Int: Int] = [:]
    private var initialPrimes = [2, 3, 5, 7]
    private var c = 9   // First candidate after fixed list

    public func next() -> Int? {

        if !initialPrimes.isEmpty {
            return initialPrimes.removeFirst()
        }

        if c == 9 {
            // Create the base prime generator and fetch the first odd prime:
            basePrimes = PostponedPrimeIterator()
            _ = basePrimes.next()
            basePrime = basePrimes.next()!
            basePrimeSquared = basePrime * basePrime
            assert(c == basePrimeSquared)
        }

        while true {
            defer { c += 2 }

            let factor: Int
            if let f = sieve.removeValue(forKey: c) {
                // `c` is divisible by `f`
                factor = f
            } else if c == basePrimeSquared {
                // `c` is the square of `p`
                factor = basePrime
                basePrime = basePrimes.next()!
                basePrimeSquared = basePrime * basePrime
            } else {
                // `c` is a prime number
                assert(c < basePrimeSquared)
                return c
            }

            // Insert next odd number which is divisiby by `factor` but not present in the sieve:
            var j = c + 2 * factor
            while sieve[j] != nil {
                j += 2 * factor
            }
            sieve[j] = factor
        }
    }
}

public struct PostponedPrimeSequence: Sequence {
    public func makeIterator() -> PostponedPrimeIterator {
        return PostponedPrimeIterator()
    }
}
```

The interesting thing about that algorithm is that the prime generator needs a
list of "base primes" which are created using another instance *of itself.*
This works because

- the base prime generator is created "delayed", after producing some fixed primes, and
- in order to generate primes up to \$ N \$, base primes are needed only up to
  \$ \sqrt N \$,

so that the creation of nested prime generators terminates eventually.
(The number of nested prime generators is \$O(\log \log N) \$, thanks to
Will Ness for [pointing that out](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/136332/postponed-prime-sieve-in-swift?noredirect=1#comment374466_136332).)

The sieving is done using a dictionary which holds the "next composite numbers" each of which is a multiple of some prime among the base primes (i.e. such that are not bigger than the square root of the current candidate).

As explained in [the above-mentioned answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10733621), the required memory
to produce \$ n \$ primes is \$ O(\sqrt n) \$.

**Example usage** (first 20 primes):

```
let p20 = Array(PostponedPrimeSequence().prefix(20))
print(p20) // [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71]
```

**Benchmarking** (measure the time to compute the 1,000,000th prime number, on a 1,2 GHz Intel Core m5
MacBook):

```
let TERMS = 1_000_000
let startTime = Date()
var gen = PostponedPrimeIterator()
for _ in 1 ..< TERMS { _ = gen.next() }
let p = gen.next()!
let endTime = Date()
let time = endTime.timeIntervalSince(startTime)
print(p, String(format: "%.02f", endTime.timeIntervalSince(startTime)), "sec")
// 15485863 1.26 sec
```

All kinds of feedback is welcome, including, but of course not limit to:

- Better type/property/variable names? I chose `PostponedPrimeIterator` because
  `Generator` was renamed to `Iterator` in Swift 3.
- As far as I have seen, all iterators in the Swift standard library are `struct`s, i.e.
  *value types,* and Apple recommends to work with value types whenever possible.
  I needed to make it a `class` because of the self-referencing property

  ```
  private var basePrimes: PostponedPrimeIterator!
  ```

  Is there a better solution?
- Swift does not have a `yield` statement as in Python, which makes some kind of
  state machine necessary: The first primes are served from an array, then the
  base prime generator is created, and from then on the primes are produced by the
  sieving algorithm. Is there a more elegant way to manage these different states?
  Can making `basePrimes` an implicitly unwrapped optional be avoided?
- `defer { c += 2 }` is called in the main loop to increment the variable even if the loop was exited via `return c`. Would you consider that a reasonable use?
  ([This](http://nshipster.com/guard-and-defer/) seems to consider it "harmful".)

Comment: [Related](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/92365/100439). Will Ness later brought his code here for (Python) optimization.

Comment: As this was the next logical step from my code, I will definitely have some things to say. I've just got to do a bit of digging through WWDC Swift3 talks to source my claims ;D

Comment: @CAD97: Thanks for the link, I hadn't seen that. Python is not my first language so it will take me a while to digest that :) – Your feedback is most welcome!

Comment: I tried replacing `var j = c + 2 * factor; etc` with `sequence(first:next:)` combined with `first(while:)`, but it more than doubled the total execution time for me. Could you check that out? I haven't figured out what caused it.

Comment: @TimVermeulen: Confirmed!

Comment: both methods are nearly identical in speed if I choose any other sequence I can think of...

Comment: If I reimplement `first(while:)`, the performance only takes a 10% penalty approximately (even though [the source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L984) isn't that much different). I'm really not sure what's going on.

Comment: [I ended up remaking this in Kotlin](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/139635/100439), if you're interested. (Who knew that generating primes is a great way to take a language through the paces! :P)

Comment: @CAD97: Unfortunately I don't know anything about Kotlin :) But I must admit that I am a bit proud of my explanation of the algorithm. Perhaps it is trivial for the people working in that field, but I found some answers on SO and CR quite terse. Thanks for quoting it with kind words!

Comment: a side note: there are O(log log N) "nested prime generators" overall because we get to N by repeated squaring (or, equivalently, we get down *from* N by repeated sqrt-ing). An interesting tidbit.

Comment: also, I'd word the next sentence after that as something like "The sieving is done using a dictionary which holds the "next composite" numbers each of which is a multiple of some prime among the base primes (i.e. such that are not bigger than the *sqrt* of the current candidate)." Just generally prefer talking about "multiples" wrt the sieve of Eratosthenes, to avoid all the confusion with the trial division sieve. for your consideration. :) (also, I don't know *any* Swift, at all. :) )

Comment: @WillNess: You are completely right, thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: @MartinR you're welcome. Now that I think about it a bit more, "some" is  not quite right. maybe use "... is done using a dictionary of "next composite" numbers, holding one multiple for each base prime ..." ? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me prefix this answer by a couple things:

- I only about 90% understand the algorithm in full. I know enough to tinker with it without breaking it, but I couldn't explain it to someone with pen and paper.
- As Swift 3 is still *beta*, some of the style guides are still up in the air. For the most part, I've tried to source purely stylistic comments from Apple's examples and documentation, but those might change and the community might end up with different ideas than Apple preached.

---

Now, addressing your points:

> Better type/property/variable names?

I fully agree on `PostponedPrimeIterator`. It agrees with prexisting types, such as [`ClosedRangeIterator`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/closedrangeiterator), [`DictionaryIterator`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/dictionaryiterator), [`EnumeratedIterator`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/enumeratediterator), etc. The only variable I would potentially rename is `private var c`, to a more descriptive name of `candidate` (as your comment clarifies).

> As far as I have seen, all iterators in the Swift standard library are `struct`s.

As far as [the reference page](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/) goes, it seems that the only `class`es in the standard library are `Managed` or [non-`@objc` for the type system](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/nonobjectivecbase).

> Is there a [way to make PostponedPrimeIterator a `struct`]?

I won't comment on whether this `Iterator` would be better as a `struct` or `class`: that's a bit philosophical and comes down to preference and your own benchmarks. However, if you do want to make it a `struct`, it is possible:

The reason that you cannot just make this a `struct` is that the compiler spits out the error `error: value type 'Type' cannot have a stored property that references itself`. The solution is to not directly recurse types, but to store a [type-erased iterator](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/anyiterator).

The changes to use `AnyIterator` and `struct`ify `PostponedPrimeIterator` are these lines:

```
private struct PostponedPrimeIterator: IteratorProtocol {
    private var basePrimes: AnyIterator<Int>!

...

public mutating func next() -> Int? {
    ...
    if c == 9 {
        basePrimes = AnyIterator(PostponedPrimeIterator())
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

In this manner you can get value semantics for your iterator. I made [a micro benchmark](https://gist.github.com/CAD97/3e614c14dabc79e9e32e1a2229371fe6) to test the cost of wrapping a simple `Array`'s `IndexingIterator` in an `AnyIterator`, which came out to about 0.006s per 10,000 items on my machine, so the cost is small but not negligible.

Again, I leave it up to you to decide if this is worth it: to me it feels like we are working against the compiler. If I am not mistaken, the reason for the compiler prohibiting simple property type recursion is that it can often lead to infinite space as each copy of the `struct` stores its own copy of the `struct` which stores its own copy of the `struct` which stores its own <snip> which leads me to my next point:

> Can making `basePrimes` an implicitly unwrapped optional be avoided?

No, and the reason is as the above recursion tells us. If `basePrimes` is a non-optional type, then it has to be initialized at the initialization step. And since this is a copy of `PostponedPrimeIterator` in `PostponedPrimeIterator`, creating a value at initialization time would lead to infinite recursion and infinite space cost. Unfortunately as I cannot find the Apple reference on implicitly unwrapped optionals at this point, I will have to link a [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24287079/3019990) about them, which states:

> Implicitly-unwrapped optionals are quite useful in cases where the value may not be present at initialization, but are set early and unlikely to become nil again.

This is the exact use-case that we have here, and as such I would say the implicitly unwrapped optional is the perfect tool to use.

> `defer { c += 2 }`

This is a matter of style and your own tastes. What I find amusing is that this effectively is a return of C-style for loops, which were removed. For example, consider these two snippets of code:

Java:

```
int c = 3;
for ( /* no initialization */ ; /* no end case */ ; c += 2) {
    if ( isPrime(c) ) return c;
}
```

Swift:

```
var c = 3
while true {
    defer { c += 2 }
    if isPrime(c) {
        return c
    }
}
```

There is a *slight* difference, as in the Swift snippet the `defer` block runs after the `return` and it does not in the Java, but it would be trivial to use `while { defer {} }` to emulate a traditional C-style loop.

The point of showing that was to say that my first thought was a C-style for loop. This turns out to be correct, but I could have as easily intuited that the `defer` block only ran after a `return` and not just after the `while` block ended.

I feel the [NSHipster article](http://nshipster.com/guard-and-defer/) goes a little far in declaring that the `defer {} return` is in itself dangerous. I do agree, however, that when the `defer`'s purpose is not immediately obvious from its context (such as when used for cleanup), it can be confusing. However, (and I'm sure an Apple example exists which I cannot find,) I think the use of `defer` right before a `return` is made clear in context. It is a bit different, but you can always see exactly when the code is going to run -- directly after the following `return`.

To draw an actual guideline from the above paragraph: use `defer` immediately following allocation for cleanup, or immediately before a `return` for code that needs to run after the `return` value is determined. As such, your loop changes in the following ways:

- remove `defer { c += 2 }` from the first line
- add `defer { c += 2 }` immediately before the only `return`
- add `c += 2` at the end of the loop

The key point here is the single exit point that the defer will be run on. The point is to keep `defer` located next to why it exists, which is in this case to run after the `return`.

I will reiterate that this particular guideline is mostly my opinion, and the opinion of the Swift community and Apple may at some point change (as in fact, mine will likely as well).

---

And now a few miscellaneous bits:

`removeFirst` and `removeLast` perform similarly. I performed [a micro benchmark](https://gist.github.com/CAD97/60d595d3543c40111190b7d60a1c314b) of `removeFirst` versus `removeLast` and `removeLast` was faster by about 1 millionth of a second on my machine. As such, you can use either. It might be negligibly faster to reverse `basePrimes` and use `removeLast`, however.

`j` at the bottom of your loop could have a descriptive name rather than a single letter. However, I do not have any suggestions, thus this being located here instead of at the top.

`let time = endTime.timeIntervalSince(startTime)` in your benchmarking code is an unused assignment. Additionally, `it` is usually the short name for iterators, rather than `gen`, as they are no longer generators.

---

These tweaks are unlikely to (noticeably) change execution time, but as always, if you are concerned about performance, test every change. The next step in optimization would be to add a wheel. But that's for another question.

---

My benchmarks were done on a Mac Mini (mid 2011) running macOS Sierra developer beta 3 with 8GB RAM, and as such my results are probably more dramatic than should be expected on modern machines.

Comment: Some quick replies: Good point about AnyIterator, that should work but might decrease the performance due to the additional level of indirection. I will test it later. – Your suggestion about defer is exactly what I had in a previous version, before I decided to remove all duplicates of "c += 2", so I can agree with that. – [removeFirst](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection/1641046-removefirst) is a protocol extension method of Collection and has complexity O(1). – `time` was meant to be used in the print statement, somehow that got duplicated.

Comment: (cont.) Thanks for the review, I will read it in more detail during the weekend.

Comment: @MartinR `removeFirst()` is indeed in a protocol extension of `Collection`, but with the constraint that `Self == SubSequence`. `Array` has implemented its own `removeFirst()` which runs in O(n) instead of O(1).

Comment: @TimVermeulen: You are right, I somehow arrived at the wrong definition. I did not make a measurable difference in my test code, that that's because the array is very short.

Comment: Btw, using AnyIterator also did not (noticeably) change the execution time of my test program.

Comment: @TimVermeulen: So you could define it as a slice: `var initialPrimes = ArraySlice([2, 3, 5, 7])`, then removeFirst() becomes O(1).

Comment: Definitely! In fact, I'd probably write `var initialPrimes: ArraySlice = [2, 3, 5, 7]`.

Answer (score 1):

@CAD97 already wrote an excellent review, I just have a couple things to add:

- I made `basePrimes` a normal optional instead of an implicitly unwrapped optional. Instead of initialising it when `c == 9`, we can unwrap it using `guard`, and initialise it if it doesn't have a value.
- I also made `basePrime` an optional because the default value of `0` was pretty arbitrary.
- `basePrimeSquared` seemed more trouble than it's worth, so I got rid of it.
- In order to reduce the number of force unwraps (`basePrimes.next()!`), I added a private `nextPrime()` function that returns a non-optional `Int`, and `next()` simply calls `nextPrime()`.
- I made `initialPrimes` an `ArraySlice` instead of an `Array` as you suggested in the comments, to make `removeFirst()` an O(1) operation instead of O(n).
- Your `while sieve[j] != nil` loop can (partly) be replaced by `sequence(start:next:)`, which allows us to get rid of `var j`.
- I added some minor tweaks, like changing an `if` into a `guard` and renaming `c` to `candidate`.

Here's the result:

```
public final class PostponedPrimeIterator: IteratorProtocol {

    private var basePrimes: PostponedPrimeIterator?
    private var basePrime: Int?

    private var sieve: [Int: Int] = [:]
    private var initialPrimes: ArraySlice = [2, 3, 5, 7]
    private var candidate = 9

    public func next() -> Int? {
        return nextPrime()
    }

    private func nextPrime() -> Int {
        guard initialPrimes.isEmpty else {
            return initialPrimes.removeFirst()
        }

        guard let basePrimes = basePrimes else {
            // Create the base prime generator:
            let basePrimes = PostponedPrimeIterator()
            self.basePrimes = basePrimes

            // Fetch the first odd prime:
            _ = basePrimes.next()
            basePrime = basePrimes.next()

            return nextPrime()
        }

        while true {
            defer { candidate += 2 }

            let factor: Int
            if let f = sieve.removeValue(forKey: candidate) {
                // `candidate` is divisible by `f`
                factor = f
            } else if let basePrime = basePrime, candidate == basePrime * basePrime {
                // `candidate` is the square of `basePrime`
                factor = basePrime
                self.basePrime = basePrimes.nextPrime()
            } else {
                // `candidate` is a prime number
                return candidate
            }

            // Insert next odd number which is divisiby by `factor` but not present in the sieve:
            let nextOddMultiples = sequence(first: candidate + 2 * factor, next: { $0 + 2 * factor })
            for nextOddMultiple in nextOddMultiples where sieve[nextOddMultiple] == nil {
                sieve[nextOddMultiple] = factor
                break
            }
        }
    }

}
```

My benchmarks indicate no significant performance difference between this code and your original code, but I got rid of all the `!`s, so I think it's an improvement :)

I'm still not really happy about the `while true` loop, but I didn't manage to get rid of it without sacrificing performance.

Comment: I am not a fan of "guard" as a general replacement for "if not", as in `guard initialPrimes.isEmpty` (but that is just my opinion). – `basePrime` has a value once the "main loop" is entered, so checking it with `if let basePrime = basePrime` seems misleading to me. – I *think* I tried a `nextPrime()` method with a `next()` wrapper and it was slower, but I am not sure anymore. – `guard let basePrimes = basePrimes` (and the recursive call of `nextPrime()`) is a good idea.

Comment: The first guard is indeed a matter of opinion. I like to generally use `guard` if it always exits the scope, but `if` works just fine. I agree that `if let basePrime = basePrime` is misleading, but it can't be unwrapped at the same time as `basePrimes` because it might change in the `while` loop. I guess there's no perfect solution.