# Postponed Prime Sequence in Kotlin

Tags: primes, iterator, kotlin

Following my previous [unbounded prime generator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/136019/100439) and [a followup by](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/136332/100439) [Martin R](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/35991/martin-r), I've tested the waters in [Kotlin](http://kotlinlang.org/) by making an unbounded sieve.

To quote Martin R's wonderful explanation of the base algorithm,

> The interesting thing about that algorithm is that the prime generator needs a list of "base primes" which are created using another instance of *itself*. This works because
>
> - the base prime generator is created "delayed", after producing some fixed primes, and
> - in order to generate primes up to \$ N \$, base primes are needed only up to \$ \sqrt N \$
>
> so that the creation of nested prime generators terminates eventually.
>
> The sieving is done using a dictionary which holds the "next composite numbers" which are divisible by any prime less than the current base prime. [As explained [on SO]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10733621), the required memory to produce \$ n \$ primes is \$ O(\sqrt n). \$

```kotlin
class PostponedPrimeSequence() : AbstractIterator<Int>(), Sequence<Int> {
    override fun iterator() = this

    private var basePrimes: PostponedPrimeSequence? = null
    private var basePrime = 0

    private var sieve = mutableMapOf<Int, Int>()
    private var initialPrimes = mutableListOf(2, 3, 5, 7)
    private var candidate = 9

    override fun computeNext() {
        if (!initialPrimes.isEmpty()) {
            setNext(initialPrimes.removeAt(0))
        } else {
            if (candidate == 9) {
                basePrimes = PostponedPrimeSequence()
                basePrimes!!.next()
                basePrime = basePrimes!!.next()
                assert(candidate == basePrime * basePrime)
            }

            while (candidate > 0) {
                val factor = sieve.remove(candidate) ?:
                        if (candidate == basePrime * basePrime) {
                            val temp = basePrime
                            basePrime = basePrimes!!.next()
                            temp
                        } else {
                            assert(candidate < basePrime * basePrime)
                            setNext(candidate)
                            break
                        }
                var j = candidate + 2 * factor
                while (sieve.containsKey(j)) {
                    j += 2 * factor
                }
                sieve[j] = factor
                candidate += 2
            }
            candidate += 2
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```kotlin
PostponedPrimeSequence().take(20).forEach(::println)
```

All feedback welcome, though reviews are encouraged to look at:

- Naming: As I'm new to Kotlin, I don't know the naming conventions yet
- Performance: If there are simple, provable improvements without drastically changing the algorithm (such as [adding a large wheel](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/92365/100439))
- Iteration organization: As Kotlin lacks a true `yield`ing generator and I wanted a true `Iterator`/`Sequence`, rather than [a callback based "poor man's `yield`"](http://jamie.mccrindle.org/2013/01/callbacks-poor-mans-yield.html), the iteration isn't exactly the prettiest matter. The `candidate += 2 } candidate += 2` bit especially feels like there should be a better way to do this, and the `break` (which is related) breaks <sup><sup><sub>ha</sub></sup></sup> simple control flow, which is not ideal.
- `!!`: Even on the line immediately following assignment to `basePrimes`, I have to use `!!` to potentially fail on accessing the `next` method (`Smart cast to 'PostponedPrimeSequence' is impossible, because 'basePrimes' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time`). I know that, due to reflection, any variable on the JVM could change at any time, but this seems <s>like a smelly smell that smells</s> smelly. `basePrimes` has to be mutable and start out `null`, though, because otherwise the class would recursively take infinite space. In this case, though, I want to initialize it once, late, and from then on it should act as an immutable (non-nullable) `val` reference. If this is possible in Kotlin, I don't know how to do so yet.

Comment: StackExchange also supports `lang-kotlin`.

Comment: @mfulton26 [Does it, though](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109)? If I read that right, it should be falling back to `default` when using `lang-kotlin`. It seems to do just as well, though, so I'll switch. (The biggest hint is `fun` is not highlighted as a keyword.)

Comment: Ha. That's funny, I figured it wasn't fully implemented, buggy, etc. You're probably right but I've always used `lang-kotlin` just the same.

Comment: a side note: if N is x repetedly squared k times, then N = x**(2**k) so that `log(log N) = log( (2**k)*log x) = k*log 2 + log(log x)` so  the height of that "tower" of "nested primes generators" is k = O(log (log N)). IOW that recursion that "terminates eventually" actually does so in O(log log N) steps. An interesting tidbit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can make `basePrimes` a `lateinit` non-null `var` to avoid `!!`.
2. `sieve` and `initialPrimes` are only assigned once so they can be marked with `val` instead of `var`
3. `sequenceOf(2, 3, 4, 7).iterator()` can be used along with `Iterator.hasNext` and `Iterator.next` instead of `mutableListOf(2, 3, 5, 7)` with somewhat difficult to read `!initialPrimes.isEmpty()` and `initialPrimes.removeAt(0)` (although if you really prefer to use a collection instead of an iterator then you can use `isNotEmpty` instead of `!collection.isEmpty`).
4. Instead of explicitly declaring a `temp` variable you can use `apply` to take the current value of a variable, use/change it, and return the initial value.
5. As an alternative to `sieve.containsKey(j)` you can use `j in sieve`.
6. As an alternative to `candidate += 2 } candidate += 2` you can move the latter `+= 2` to relatively the beginning of `computeNext` (requires a few other changes, see below). The name `candidate` would no longer really fit though, but I think a generic property name like `value` is sufficient enough (we know what "value" we care about so we know what we're computing as we go, etc.).
7. You probably shouldn't implement `Iterator<Int>` and `Sequence<Int>` in the same object. e.g. When invoking `with(PostponedPrimeSequence()) { repeat(2) { take(20).forEach(::println) } }` I would expect it as a `Sequence<Int>` to print the first 20 primes twice (or throw "IllegalStateException: This sequence can be consumed only once.") but as an `Iterator<Int>` I would expect it to print the first 40 primes. These are conflicting expectations. I recommend only implementing one. A `Sequence` is understood to possibly be constrained to be iterated only once so I would implement the base `Iterator` and then wrap it as a `Sequence` in a top-level function for convenience.

e.g.

```
fun generatePrimeSequence() = PostponedPrimeIterator().asSequence()

class PostponedPrimeIterator() : AbstractIterator<Int>() {
    private lateinit var basePrimes: PostponedPrimeIterator
    private var basePrime = 0

    private val sieve = mutableMapOf<Int, Int>()
    private val initialPrimes = sequenceOf(2, 3, 5, 7).iterator()
    private var value = 0

    override fun computeNext() {
        if (initialPrimes.hasNext()) {
            value = initialPrimes.next()
            setNext(value)
        } else {
            value += 2

            if (value == 9) {
                basePrimes = PostponedPrimeIterator()
                basePrimes.next()
                basePrime = basePrimes.next()
                assert(value == basePrime * basePrime)
            }

            while (value > 0) {
                val factor = sieve.remove(value) ?:
                        if (value == basePrime * basePrime) {
                            basePrime.apply {
                                basePrime = basePrimes.next()
                            }
                        } else {
                            assert(value < basePrime * basePrime)
                            setNext(value)
                            break
                        }
                var j = value + 2 * factor
                while (j in sieve) {
                    j += 2 * factor
                }
                sieve[j] = factor
                value += 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
generatePrimeSequence().take(20).forEach(::println)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just compared two solution suggested above in term of performance:

```
    println("PostponedPrimeSequence: ${measureTimeMillis { PostponedPrimeSequence().take(10000).sum().let(::println) }}")
    println("generatePrimeSequence: ${measureTimeMillis { generatePrimeSequence().take(10000).sum().let(::println) }}")
```

I've been surprised that performance diffs about 2 times:

```
496165411
PostponedPrimeSequence: 23
496165411
generatePrimeSequence: 48
```

Comment: As always, benchmarking the JVM is troublesome. Make sure that you aren't accidentally measuring startup time. It'd also be more fair to compare `PostponedPrimeIterator()` to my `PostponedPrimeSequence()` due to the requirement of the `asSequence` wrapper.

Comment: Answers should be able to stand on their own. As is, this answer is dependent on another to be of any use and could be voted Not An Answer because of that. I'd suggest fleshing out your answer to avoid that. A demonstration of performance deltas could potentially stand on its own if you successfully demonstrate that you are measuring what you purport to be measuring, and it isn't overshadowed by overhead.

Comment: (If and where you refer to another post or comment, please plant a link for disambiguation. You can find one for posts as [`share`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/181724/93149) immediately underneath. For a [comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/139635/postponed-prime-sequence-in-kotlin/181724#comment261343_139635), find it "below the date".)